# Wildcards not interpreted by shell script when used with output redirection

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, wildcards

Say I have two scripts:

- script1.sh:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  version=2.6
  log_file="$HOME/log-file-version-$version.log"

  touch $log_file &>/dev/null

  echo "log to my log file from script 1" >> $HOME/log-file-version-?.?.log

  gnome-terminal --tab --active --title="script2" --  sh script2.sh
  ```
- script2.sh:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  echo "log to my log file from script 2" >> $HOME/log-file-version-?.?.log
  ```

I run `script1.sh`.

I'm left with two log files in my home:

```
log-file-version-2.6.log
log-file-version-?.?.log
```

`log-file-version-2.6.log` contains:

> log to my log file from script 1

`log-file-version-?.?.log` contains:

> log to my log file from script 2

which means that in script 1 the wildcards from line 7 (`>> $HOME/log-file-version-?.?.log`) were correctly interpreted, but when a script is run with `sh` these wildcards don't work.

Why is that and how can I fix this?

I need to use wildcards because I don't want to be passing arguments from shell script to shell script and I want them to be self-sufficient.

I'm using Ubuntu and running these scripts from the default terminal which is gnome-terminal.

Comment: Upvoted because the question is clear and reproducible -- and I learned something new about the differences in how POSIX-compliant shells behave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bash manual has this to say in the [3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) section:

> The word following the redirection operator in the following descriptions, unless otherwise noted, is subjected to brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, quote removal, **filename expansion**, and word splitting. If it expands to more than one word, Bash reports an error.

`sh` does not do that: from the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07)

> If the redirection operator is "`<<`" or "`<<-`", [...]. **For the other redirection operators,** the word that follows the redirection operator shall be subjected to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal. **Pathname expansion shall not be performed on the word by a non-interactive shell;** an interactive shell may perform it, but shall do so only when the expansion would result in one word.

```
$ dash
$ echo foo > *
$ ls
'*'  README.md  ...
```

```
$ bash
$ echo bar >> *
bash: *: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: thank you! much clearer. although I had no particular use for sh if bash could accomplish the same. I just forgot about bash. do you think sh is more appropriate here?

Comment: Why are you putting wildcards on the RHS of a redirection? Why don't you already know the filename? What if there are more than one matching file?

Comment: @tatsu Redirecting to a file glob with `bash` is only appropriate if you _know_ that the glob will expand to a single file, always. Ideally, you should hand the correct filename to the script on the command line instead (in which case it does not matter if you use `bash` or `sh`).

Comment: This is a much better answer as it explains the underlying reason why the behaviour of `sh` (actually `dash` in this case) differs from that of `bash`.

Comment: actually I just wanted to know why that wasn't working, it was bugging me, but of course the parent script knows the full name and can pass that as a variable, which (of course) is more robust, I guess being in the middle of testing something and lazyness got the better of me but now I'll probably pass it as a variable.